# Magento2. Knockout. Translation doesn't work

Tags: magento2, localisation, knockoutjs

Please advice is there any pre-requirements to translate in *.html files

Works:

```
<button type="submit" class="action primary"><span>Send link to a Friend</span></button>
```

Don't want to work:

```
<button type="submit" class="action primary"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Send link to a Friend'"></span></button>
```

Translation in `i18n/en_US.csv` exists. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
<button type="submit" class="action primary">
  <span data-bind="text: $t('Send link to a Friend')"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the templates view component has the `mage/translate` dependency, also make sure that you re-generate your static view files.

Use a language pack, placed in `app/i18n`, instead of placing the translations in a module or theme. Translations of js files has been buggy, but using a language pack has worked for me in version 2.1.6+. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7525).